# syntax error, unexpected token "{", expecting "function" or "const"

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error

```
Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

> syntax error, unexpected token "{", expecting "function" or "const"

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You forgot to tell us which line the error is thrown by. It doesn't obviously seem to be any of the ones here. The error message will list it. Please always provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: You can also take a look at the plentiful guidance at [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: you should share your import statements for a proper answer as well.